# My Macbook Pro doesn't give any reaction when pressing the power button

Tags: macos, mac, troubleshooting, macbook

An hour ago I closed the display my Macbook Pro. it goes into sleep mode. After dinner I returned, opened the display and wanted to continue with my work, but I recognized it was switched off completely.

I tried to press the power button and received nothing. I also noticed that the green light on the power supply plug which is plugged into my Macbook is off. Same thing with a power supply from the Mac of a friend of mine.

What could I try? Some suggestions? What could be the problem here??

I already tried using the battery to start, no success, also taking the battery out completely, no success. Even if I press the small button for showing the current battery charge, none of the leds starts. It's like the Mac is completely dead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's toasted. Take it to the nearest Apple store and pray.

Comment: How can that be? It didn't do any high computations, nothing...damn it.

Comment: Stuff happens. Sometimes it's a fluke, other times it's not. Best to just take it in and let them diagnose it. If it's under AppleCare you're all set.

Comment: Just to conclude this topic. You were right. The motherboard was dead. What a luck it was still in warranty. 2 weeks later and I could have payed it by myself...

Answer (score 1):

Try an [SMC reset](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964).

Comment: Thx for that info. I tried that already, but it doesn't seem to work. Should I hear some sound, something that the reset succeeded?? 'Cause I followed the instructions, removed battery and everything, did the reset by pressing 5 secs the power button, then put the battery again, but no success... :(

Comment: @Juri if the battery test button doesn't show any lights at all, that battery is fully drained. I've sometimes seen fully, fully drained batteries keep a machine from booting. Try doing the SMC reset, leaving the battery out, reconnecting the AC adaptor (make sure it's plugged into an outlet that has power), and then try to boot the machine.

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely a **battery issue**. I doubt it's the computer itself, but if you want you could take it into your nearest [Apple Store](http://apple.com/retail). They will look at it and tell you the issue. You're probably going to have to just pay for a new battery which is about **$100** (googled it).

Wish you the best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Few options to try... (*each a different option*)

1. Shut down your Mac, press the power button, and as soon as you hear the startup chime, hold down Command-Option-P-R. Keep holding down those keys until you hear a second startup chime. Then let go and allow your Mac to continue starting normally.
2. Make sure the Mac is plugged in to AC power. On the built-in keyboard, press and hold the Shift, Option, and Control keys on the left side and press the power button. Release all the keys at once, and then turn the Mac on normally.
3. Hit the power button then hold Command-R
4. Apple store (*It's probably a hardware issue*)

source: http://www.macworld.com/article/2881177/how-to-reset-your-macs-nvram-pram-and-smc.html , https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201295 , Own experience